# Multiple ListBox selection avoiding duplicates VBA

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I am building a Userform which contains two ListBoxes such that the user can select options from ListBox1 and add them to ListBox2 or alternatively remove options from ListBox2

What I am struggling with is how can I prevent the duplicates from being added to the ListBox2? Essentially, I want to build in a function (?) which checks if an option is already included in ListBox2

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'### Adds Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)
Next i

ListBox1.Selected

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

'### Removes Items from ListBox2
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i - counter) Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem (i - counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a check using COntains function

Comment: Please post a link to your image...

Comment: Not sure how contains function would work in VBA. However, I have found another similar thread on stackoverflow which solves a similar problem and working to adjust it to my needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755920/prevent-duplicates-from-adding-items-from-listbox1-to-listbox2-vba-excel

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked as a solution to the problem:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        valCheck (ListBox1.List(i))
    End If

Next i

End Sub

Private Function valCheck(str As String)

'### Adds Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2

Dim valExists As Boolean

    valExists = False


        For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1

            If ListBox2.List(i) = str Then
                valExists = True
            End If

        Next i

        If valExists Then
            MsgBox ("already exists")
        Else
            ListBox2.AddItem str
        End If





End Function
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

'### Removes Items from ListBox2

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox2.RemoveItem (i)

Next i



End Sub
```